# Lost trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have *lost* a trigger. I know it is active, since when I try to change a field, it restores its value back, and from the SQL Server Management Studio I can see that when I execute the query, an extra one is executing (the trigger one).

I tried `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE 1 = 1` but it does not return anything. Also, I know the name of the trigger, but when I try to `ALTER`it returns an error saying that

> the name of the object 'myTrigger' is not valid.

And if I try to `DROP TRIGGER myTrigger ON DATABASE`

> Trigger 'myTrigger' can not be removed because it does not exists, or the user has not enough priviledges.

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious here but 1) make sure you are executing the select statement on the actual database you expect the trigger to be on and 2) verify you are using the correct owner to view the trigger.

Comment: " or the user has not enough priviledges." may provide a hint to a reason you may not be able to see the trigger - what permissions do you have in the database?

Comment: Is the trigger a database trigger as the drop command indicates or a different type of trigger (e.g. server or table)

Comment: @Lieven By the gods!! I have not seen that when I hitted "New query" the upper sleect was pointing to other DB... How silly... 2 hours lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as Lieven said, I was not querying the right database... This is odd, since the query had the DB defined on it

```
ALTER TRIGGER myTrigger
ON [DB].[dbo].[table]
```

But the upper select of the SQL Server Management Studio was pointing to other DB...

---

**Edit:**
I have been investigating a little bit (trying to clean my image), and I found a weird behaviour on SQL Server Management Studio.
If you execute a query like:

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[table] SET column = 'value' WHERE column2 = 'foo'
```

It executes the query in the right DB. No matter what DB is pointed by the upper select.

**But**, if you try to do the same, with a trigger, you must have the upper select pointing the right DB, or you will face the same problems I had.

Comment: Welcome to the "Hall of Shame" and don't worry, you'll never catch up with me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a subtle error kind of like yours; I did something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TrigCustomerInsertDelete] 

ON [mobile].[Customers] 

AFTER INSERT, DELETE   
AS  

    select 'I'  [ACTION],* from inserted
    select 'D'  [ACTION],* from deleted

GO
```

and then later tried to update it with:

ALTER TRIGGER [TrigCustomerInsertDelete]

and got this error: Invalid object name

The problem was that I did not specify the schema on the trigger (thinking it would just be dbo), but the table does have a schema.  So, I figured out the error after including the schema on the trigger.

CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[TrigCustomerInsertDelete]

This gave me the following error: Cannot create trigger 'DBO.TrigCustomerInsertDelete' because its schema is different from the schema of the target table or view.

I know this is an old post, but hopefully it will help someone else.